# jqGrid: Not able to get data in subgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 4.4.1 with subGrid.

I am pulling different  kind of data but for this sample data, I am not able to get subGrid when click on "Expand".

Here is the sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>SubGrid Real Data</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<style>
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid td.subgrid-data {
        border-top: 0 none !important;
        border-right: 0 none !important;
        border-bottom: 0 none !important;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid span.ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-sw {
                background-color: #FFFFFF !important; 
                background-image: none !important;
                border: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint browser: true, eqeq: true, plusplus: true */
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var colModelData =[
            {"width":"300","name":"itemName","editable":false}
            ],
        colNamesArray = ["Name"],
        subColModel = [
            {"width":"300","name":"itemName","editable":false}
            ],  

        myData = [{"id":"metlab panel","itemName":"Metlab Panel",
        "subGridData":[
            {"itemName":"CMP BILIRUBIN,TOTAL"},
            {"itemName":"CMP CALCIUM"},
            {"itemName":"CMP CREATININE"},
            {"itemName":"CMP POTASSIUM"},
            {"itemName":"CMP PROTEIN,TOTAL"},
            {"itemName":"CMP SODIUM"},
            {"itemName":"CMP GLUCOSE"}]
        }];

        $("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: myData,
            colNames: colNamesArray,
            colModel: colModelData,
            gridview: true,
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            caption: "Create subgrid from local data",
            subGrid: true,
            subGridOptions: {
                reloadOnExpand: false,
                selectOnExpand: false
            },
            subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, parentRowId) {

                    var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>");
                    $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
                    var data = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", parentRowId);
                    console.log(data.subGridData); // I can see data
                    $subgrid.jqGrid({
                            datatype: "local",
                            data: data.subGridData,
                            colModel:subColModel,
                            height: "100%",
                            width: "100%",
                            autoencode: true,
                            gridview: true,
                            rowNum: 200

                    });
            $subgrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                    .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").hide();
        }   

        });
    });

//]]>
</script>
```

### Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is incorrect working with `id`.

The first error is the usage of `id` having blanks. If you replace `"id":"metlab panel"` with for example `"id":"metlabpanel"` one will see the subgrid already.

The next problem is that the data for subgrid has no `id` as all. In the case jqGrid will use values 1, 2, 3, ... as the rowid. If one would expand at least two subgrids you will have id duplicates which will be a problem. To solve the problem can use `idPrefix` for subgrid which is created based on the rowid of the parent. For example

```
idPrefix: "s_" + parentRowId + "_"
```

In any way you should *always* think to provide unique rowid for every row of main grid or subgrid.

[The modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HardikMishra1.htm) display the subgrid correctly

[image]

The best will be to fill `id` property for every row or grid or subgrid which you create. If you not sure which value you want to assign you can just call `$.jgrid.randId()` which will provide safe unique value which you can use as `id`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,. I have unique item id in my data for each row. But I removed it from the demo. And Yes, Id with space skipped from my mind. :)

Comment: If you could tell on How to remove the "icon" from sub grid cell. I tried to alter CSS for `ui-widget-content subgrid-cell` but didn't work

Comment: @HardikMishra: You are welcome! I don't understand whether the problem "Not able to get data in subgrid" is solved after fixing `id`s or not? You should not place *multiple independent questions in one question*. The goal of stackoverflow is sharing questions and answers with other. Commutative questions are very difficult for indexing so other people will probably not find the required information.

Comment: :Thanks for the suggestion.  Will take care in the future. :)